# How to Detect if Sprite is going Up or Down

Tags: vb.net, xna, windows-phone

I Use the following code to detect if a sprite should be going up or down and the response

```
    If (pos.Y + 100) >= Sprite.BottomY Then
        Going_up = True
        pos.Y = Sprite.BottomY - 130
    End If
    If pos.Y <= Sprite.TopY Then
        Going_up = False
        pos.Y = Sprite.TopY - 1
        Vel.Y = 3
    End If
```

then

```
        If Going_up Then
        Vel.Y -= CSng(gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalMilliseconds / 40)
        pos.Y -= Vel.Y
    Else
        Vel.Y += CSng(gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalMilliseconds / 40)
        pos.Y += Vel.Y

    End If

    Sprite.velocity = Vel
    Sprite.position = pos
```

but it's pretty terrible. It only works when the sprite starts at the top, and when I want to change the BottomY and TopY, it just starts glitching. What is a better to detect if the sprite should be going up or down?

Comment: You may also have luck searching / posting in http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: What is it exactly that you are trying to achieve? What is pos and what do you expect to happen depending on what it is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you not just do:

```
If (Vel.Y > 0) Then

    Going_up = True
    ' Do rest of up code
Else If (Vel.Y < 0) Then

    Going_up = False
    ' Do rest of not going up code
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

Something that might help is utilizing a getter and setter like [this](http://books.google.com/books?id=r84zVNETwa0C&pg=PA18&lpg=PA18&dq=xna%20sprite%20properties&source=bl&ots=Z_rzA1dDxb&sig=XgLdThn-n3BLbxkFyDA26S38ENo&hl=en&sa=X&ei=NF57T6TPNIPq2QXZ0PieAw&ved=0CCQQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=xna%20sprite%20properties&f=false):
Essentially, you could create a tempX and tempY. Every 100ms compare the sprite's current properties with the temp variables.

```
Dim tempX As Double
Dim tempY As Double
While True 
   tempY = sprite.GetY()
   If gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalMilliseconds Mod 100 = 0 Then 'or something to sample the game time
      If sprite.Vel.Y > tempY Then
         Going_up = True
      Else
         Going_up = False
      End If
   End IF
End While
```

So you're sort of taking a sample of your game board to create approximate reference points that you can compare the actual value to. Hope that helps!

-sf